# Find image and use mouse_event

Tags: mousemove

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (; ; )
        {
            string[] search = UseImageSearch("*30 img\\img.bmp");




            if (search == null)
                continue;

            int[] search_ = new int[search.Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < search.Length; j++)
            {
                search_[j] = Convert.ToInt32(search[j]);
            }



            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 0, 0, 0);



        }

     }
```

I want to use mouse events to move the mouse over there when I find the image.

mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 0, 0, 0, 0);

I do not know how to fix this place.